# Magento 2: Modal opens only once

Tags: magento2, modal-popup

Here is my HTML and JS:

```
<div id="mybutton" class="button">
    click
</div>

<div id="testcontent">
    blah
</div>


<script>
    // <![CDATA[
    require([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ], function ($) {
        $(function () {
            $('#mybutton').on('click', function(){
                $('#testcontent').modal({
                    title: 'My Title',
                    autoOpen: true
                });
            });
        });
    });
    // ]]>
</script>
```

**The Problem is:** the modal works only once. After closing it the button does not spawn a second modal.

Comment: Set "autoOpen: true" To "autoOpen: false"

Comment: Doesn't change anything.

Comment: Have you got any error in console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.modal({...options})` will only set up the modal (and auto open if `autoOpen: true`). You should instruct the modal to open by passing `"openModal"` to it (`.modal("openModal")`).

Try this code:

```
<div id="mybutton" class="button">
    click
</div>

<div id="testcontent" style="display:none;">
    blah
</div>

<script>
require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ],
    function(
        $,
        modal
    ) {
        var options = {
            type: 'popup',
            responsive: true,
            innerScroll: true,
            modalClass: 'mybuttont_modal',
            title: 'testcontent'
        };

        var popup = modal(options, $('#testcontent'));
        $("#mybutton").on('click',function(){ 
            $("#testcontent").modal("openModal");
        });

    }
);
</script>
```

Comment: Thx, that did it.

Comment: @Prashant next time also add an explanation of what your code is doing differently and why it is that way.